¿Por qué seguimos sin poder migrar preguntas a StackOverflow en otros idiomas o a otros sitios de la red?
Estoy al tanto de la publicación de gbianchi de hace unos 7 años: ¿Por qué no migrar las preguntas en ingles directamente a SO inglés?.
Sin embargo, no tiene una respuesta aceptada y quizás es algo que haga falta gestionar con un CM o de lo que haya un NO definitivo, pero considero que sería necesario y útil que la comunidad pueda migrar las preguntas que eventualmente aparecen en otras lenguas, como esta de hoy.
Incluso, he visto alguna publicación en portugués.
Lo cierto es que, en lugar de cerrarlas por estar en otro idioma pienso que sería más apropiado migrarlas.

Por ahora, la comunidad solo puede migrar a meta.
Como referencia, dejo una imagen de esta misma pantalla en StackOverflow (en inglés):

¿Qué tenemos que hacer, como comunidad, para lograrlo?

Cuando aparece una pregunta en español en SOen se migran para acá (es algo obvio), no sé si sea igual de "obvio" cuando pasa el caso contrario (preguntas en ingles en SOes), muchas veces veo que el OP es de habla hispana y solo por desconocimiento y/o confusión ha realizado la pregunta en inglés. No son pocas las veces que se les indica el problema y traducen la pregunta. En otras circunstancias habría estado 1000% a favor de esto, pero ahora con el bajo volumen de preguntas prefiero que las preguntas se cierren y que exista la posibilidad que el OP la traduzca para reabrirla

@Yussef quien te dijo que migran de SOen para aca? eso no es cierto. No hay migraciones entre SOx de ningun tipo....

@gbianchi Acá me aparecen https://es.stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=migrated&daterange=last30days

ok.. entonces hay migraciones solo de SOen para aca, muy contadas, y no se porque, porque no es lo que se acordo... pero bueno...

@gbianchi si hay un acuerdo previo, agradecería que respondas a mi pregunta haciendo ver eso y, de ser posible, enlazando dicho acuerdo.

Acabo de probarlo, y en la lista de lugares a migrar me deja migrar a absolutamente cualquier lado.. no se desde cuando esta asi...

Seguramente te aparecen todos porque vos sos moderador, ¿no?. En spanish, sitio de la red donde yo lo soy, me aparece un cuadro de búsqueda y puedo migrar a dónde sea (bien para un moderador). Yo me refiero al proceso de la comunidad (agregué un pantallazo para que veas como nos aparece a los simples mortales). No pido que sea algo abierto pero, al menos a los otros  SO's, más que nada por el tema de idiomas.

Con la captura de pantalla y los comentarios, ahora creo comprender hacia dónde va la la pregunta: según entiendo, no es que no se pueda migrar a otros sitios las preguntas, sino que los usuarios comunes no podemos reportar como motivo de cierre que la pregunta pertenece a otro sitio que no sea aquí (en Meta). ¿Es así?

@padaleiana, Según recuerdo, pero puedo estar equivocado, al completar el cierre de una pregunta indicando otro sitio como destino, se hace la migración de la misma hacia ese otro sitio. Es como recuerdo que funciona en SO en inglés. Edito la pregunta e incluyo imagen como referencia.

Claro, eso sí. Entonces la pregunta se refiere a las opciones que aparecen al reportar (donde si se concreta el cierre, se migra), no a migrar directamente como tal.

@padaleiana No me viene a la mente otra forma de migrar directamente, ¿cuál es esa?. Es decir, si tenemos la opción allí, quizás no haga falta realmente en esta que yo refiero.

A lo que voy es que los moderadores pueden migrar directamente (según entiendo), y que los usuarios comunes solo podemos reportar como para migrar una pregunta. Hay una pequeña gran diferencia allí.

Hasta donde sé, los moderadores usan la misma ruta para migrar. Solo que su voto es definitivo y tienen más opciones de destinos. Pero mi pregunta desde el inicio ha sido por el proceso de migración de la comunidad, en línea con A Theory of Moderation.

@padaleiana hay más información sobre el proceso en el meta general (en inglés).
